# Creating an explosion in blender game engine?

Tags: game-engine

I'm making a game in the blender game engine and i wanted to make a explosive, I've looked all over the internet, and blender.stackexchange, but no results other than videos. I cannot view long videos since as i have slow internet and a download limit.

So to make it clear, i want a explosion, I've made one, pretty bad one but it works, but it does make things fly away, it just pushes them since as it's a expanding sphere.

download the .blend here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4psdrb2zf8xcs7x/Cube%20assault%20%3B%29.blend?dl=0

Comment: what do you want this explosion to do to the surrounding objects? Do you want to know how to make an explosion graphic, or the mechanics that makes the explosion interact with the environment? It is very easy to make the explosion damage/destroy other objects, but it is entirely different to make a physics-based explosion that propels dynamic / rigid body objects away.

Comment: Good news! the cool people community on [blenderArtists.org](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?380223-Explosions) created some very nice codes for blender game engine explosions! 
[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=457" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/457/)

Comment: @X-27 Well, both really. It's meant to be a low-poly explosion from a also low-ploy rocket. if the rocket hits a turret, the turret is removed, but there's no explosion radius that damages it. Also, if i fire near it the explosion doesn't make it fly away.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding sphere (or hemisphere) is a good way to create an explosion. You might want to scale it faster.

Comment: Currently, the sphere at default scale, starts at frame 1, then scales 10x that within 10 frames. I'll try making it faster though.

Comment: Making it faster seems to be worse, i'll upload my .blend into the main question.

Comment: if making it faster was worse, you may need to increase your physics steps for the game.

Comment: @VincentScalia If that's going to make it lag, that i'm guessing it will, i won't be able to do that, slow computer. :/